# Passing arrays through Forms in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pass multiple arrays via a form to a Laravel Controller and attach form values to a relationship.

I've tried to loop through the Request array but i get an 'undefined index' error and i know i'm not getting to the data somehow. Thanks in advance.

```
form.php

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('/trs') }}">
  @csrf
<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="{{ $item->name }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="{{ $item->product_id }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="{{ $item->price }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
 Buy
</button>
 </form

Controller

  public function purchase(Request $request)
  {
         $data = $request->except('_token');
         $user= User::find(Auth::user()->id);
             foreach ($data as $item) {
              $ids = $item['product_id'];
              $names = $item['name'];
              $prices = $item['price'];
              $quantities = $item['quantity'];
              $orders->products()->attach([$ids => ['quantity' => $quantities, 'price' => $prices]]);
           }
  }
```

Comment: how is your `product_id` being submitted through the request?  i don't see a hidden input for that in form.php.  trying to access `$item['product_id']` when `product_id` hasn't been set might explain why you are getting that error.

Comment: why are you trying to use arrays, you have one set of values?

Comment: @lagbox it's not a set, they are dynamic so could have more than one of each.

Comment: @Erich i've edited the question. The issue isn't with the product_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foreach` is iterating over the inputs, not the arrays in those inputs:

```
foreach ($data as $item)
```

In the first iteration `$item` is the `name` array. In the second iteration `$item` is the `product_id` array, etc. `name` doesn't have an index named `name`, `price` or `quantity`, its indexes are numerical (0-indexed).

One way would be to iterate those inputs specifically which are arrays:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['names']); $i++) {
    $name = $data['name'][$i];
    $product_id = $data['product_id'][$i];
    $price = $data['price'][$i];

    ...
}
```

There are assumptions being made here but hopefully that illustrates what you need to do if you want to keep using the inputs named the way they are currently.

**Updated:**

If you wanted to change the names of the inputs you might have an easier time with them being grouped:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[{{ $item->id }}][name]" value="{{ $item->name }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[{{ $item->id }}][price]" value="{{ $item->price }}" />
...

foreach ($request->input('items', []) as $id => $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    $price = $item['price'];
    ...
}
```

Now the inputs that relate to a single item are grouped into an array together by the item's id.

When you are adding fields dynamically you will have to make sure you are also using this similar naming which includes a key to group them by, in this case the 'id'.

```
items[27][name]
items[27][price]
...
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Is there a better way to pass the inputs though?

Comment: @LDUBBS similar to **Saly 3301**'s answer, i updated my answer for you

Answer (score 1):

If your form is inside a `foreach` of items collection, set the item ID as the array name and the attributes as keys like so

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('/trs') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ $item->id }}[product_id]" value="{{ $item->id }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ $item->id }}[name]" value="{{ $item->name }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ $item->id }}[price]" value="{{ $item->price }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ $item->id }}[quantity]" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Buy
    </button>
</form
```

If you do `$request->all()` you'll see that there are no `name` or `price` keys, all keys are just `0` so you have to set them explicitly

`<sidenote>` Do you really have a route named `/trs`? shouldn't that be a `url('/trs')`? `</sidenote>`

`<sidenote>` You can get the authenticated user by just `auth()->user()` `</sidenote>`

Hope this helps